# osmdroid 6.1.2: flood of draw() invocations on mapview overlays

Tags: overlay, draw, android-mapview, osmdroid

I have written a map application with osmdroid, which uses several overlays, standard ones (CopyrightOverlay, ScaleBarOverlay, etc.)  plus own implementations (e.g. for a north arrow). All these classes consist of a constructor and a function "draw()". I found that each draw function is invoked several times per second, even for static conditions (no zoom or scroll is applied, no invalidate() is called, no android life cycle events occur). I don't understand, why this happens and what is it good for.

I mean, the app works fine, but has a constant CPU load in the background, slowing down the app slightly. What's the point in updating the copyright notice several times per second?

Comment: Apparently you have already invested some time into debugging the problem. Maybe creating an issue on Github and discussing this with the developers of the library would be a bit better option than asking on StackOverflow. This kind of question is going to be hard to answer here (apart from "you are doing this and this wrong" but it seems to me that might not be the case). Checkout https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/new they have labels like "question" and "performance" for issues.

Comment: @Josef Adamcik: Very good idea. I have done that, see [link](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1498)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by the osmdroid team, as of release 6.1.6. See [here](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1498)